# Lightning Salesforce - Have to clear site data in Chrome/Firefox after making changes

Tags: lightning

Changes are not reflected in Chrome and Firefox after lightning components are saved.

Have to clear site data to be able to test new changes in code. Neither Hard Reload nor Empty Cache and Hard Reload work.

Chrome Version 54.0.2840.99 m

Anyone else has experienced this? And any solution?

Comment: I'm using the same version, and it's working here. Are you sure your changes are actually being saved, or perhaps that where are saving errors?

Comment: Yes, changes are being saved. And no, no error in code.
When I clear site data and refresh the page, then I get to test my changes.

But only a simple refresh do not reflect my changes in the code.

Weird.

Comment: I use [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) chrome extension to clear my cache when these kind of things happen. Just look at the options - you can clear also the cookies and so, see if something helps